# Can a title of a select option be styled through css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a title related to a select option.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" title="title exemplu">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" title="title exemplu">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes" title="title exemplu">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi" title="title exemplu">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I am not sure if this can be styled, I did not manage to find it here answered. I only found an answer related to the option styling. 
I saw another answer where people styled titles, but related to a link:
http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/

Comment: no, title of any element cannot be styled

Answer (score 0):

No.. you cannot style the default title but yes you can create tooltip for it and you can style it as you want.

**HTML**

```
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in an desirable way.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/qmyg9d6s/

Comment: I posted an exact similar example, where a tooltip/restyled title is added to a link. What I would have wanted is a title styling done on a option tag. I however think that is not possible...

Comment: The post is asking for <option> tag specifically. This doesn't work on that.